# Which is the best way to install ios and android app without appstore and market?

Tags: android, ios

I want to allow for visitors of some exhibition install and test my app that doesn't listed in app store and android market at this moment. And of course I don't know any id of visitor devices.
Is it possible and which is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android you could put your app in a Dropbox folder of yours. Then using an app like ZXing barcode scanner share that link as a QR code in an email to yourself. Extract the .png image from the email (maybe enlarge it) and print it out again. Attach the QR code to the welcome poster at the exhibition and invite visitors to scan it with their Android phone (assuming they have a barcode scanner app on their phone - if not suggest they download a free one from Google Play). They can then install the app easily, as scanning the code will download it.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer the .apk file(for android) to the user's phone through bluetooth so that people can install your app

Answer (score 1):

check hockeyApp http://www.hockeyapp.net/

You upload your app on it, and register "testers",

they receive a mail with a link to download the app(for iPhone you need to provision the phones).

After the installation it sends back crash reports with the type of the device and the OS version. I think it's a great tool for what you need.

It has a free version.

Answer (score 1):

Currently only for iOS but have a look at [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com)